# concat JSON into one array - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to merge two API call. I first call I get some data by filtering accound_id on backend.
In second call I am getting data with test_id.

This is my JSON for /api/test-overview:

```
{
testSprint: [
    {
    account_id: 27,
    test_id: 3,
    name: "Junior"
    },
    {
    account_id: 27,
    test_id: 50,
    name: "Wilson"
    }
 ]
}
```

This is my JSON for activityAvgService when test_id is 3:

```
{
test_id: "3",
stats: {
    avgE: 2.5,
    avgD: 43.3,
    avgA: 5.7,
    avgH: 6.3,
 highH: 0
 }
}
```

And this is JSON when test_id is 50:

```
{
test_id: "50",
stats: {
    avgE: 1,
    avgD: 33,
    avgA: 3,
    avgH: 1,
    highH: 0
  }
}
```

And this is my $http request in my controller.

```
$http.get("/api/test-overview").then(testResponse => {
        $scope.test = testResponse.data.testSprint;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.test.length; i++) {
            activityAvgService.showStatsAVG($scope.test[i].test_id).then(response => {

                var stats = response.data.stats

                console.log("stats", stats);
            });
        }
        console.log("$scope.test", $scope.
```

I want to concat that three JSON in first JSON /api/test-overview.

I would like to have something like this:

```
    {
        testSprint: [
            {
                account_id: 27,
                test_id: 3,
                name: "Junior",
                stats: {
                    avgE: 2.5,
                    avgD: 43.3,
                    avgA: 5.7,
                    avgH: 6.3,
                highH: 0
                }
            },
            {
                account_id: 27,
                test_id: 50,
                name: "Wilson",
                test_id: "50",
                stats: {
                    avgE: 1,
                    avgD: 33,
                    avgA: 3,
                    avgH: 1,
                    highH: 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I tried with map and concat but it doesn't help. Any idea how can I do

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you had JSON you would have a **`string`**. You have objects! There is no JSON (string!!!) anywhere in sight in your question! Do you want to concatenate strings or merge objects/arrays? The contents of a JSON `string` may be encoded data - but unless you decode it back into an object it still is a `string`. Or you decode - but then you don't have any "JSON" any more! So, do you have decoded data (no JSON!) or JSON-encoded data (`string`)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock the *index value* `i` for which internal ajax call is being made.

Try this

```js
$http.get("/api/test-overview").then(testResponse => {
      $scope.test = testResponse.data.testSprint;
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.test.length; i++) {
        (function(test, i) {
          activityAvgService.showStatsAVG(test[i].test_id).then(response => {
            var stats = test[i].stats; //this value will reflect in outer test in below console.log
            console.log(test, stats);
          });
        })($scope.test, i)
      }
    }
```